# DataGrid header alignment

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I populate a DataGrid control using DataSet in WPF(c#). I need a way align text of header to center.

**Note**: During running of my program, It is possible to DataGrid.ItemsSource updated.
It is not same as my previous questions...

Comment: Is this the same question you've asked several times already and each time shot down the idea of using a Style Setter and dismissed it as "unpractical"?

Comment: The same question you have repeating several time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195655/how-set-alignment-of-cell-data-to-center-in-datagrid/18201961#18201961

Comment: (to Vimal CK) That post has a static column(firstName). and in this post I need align to center header(s).

Comment: I've already provided you SO links of the particular answers but I guess you just want the direct code and don't want to try anything on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew. You answer me at today for two or three times

Answer (score 0):

You just have to style the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property of the `DataGridColumnHeader` type.  So add to the resources:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

---

**Addendum** In general, you can see the [control templates at this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248.aspx), which allows you to deduce how to apply the styles you need.  In this case, the template for the control `DataGridColumnHeader` looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Border x:Name="columnHeaderBorder" BorderThickness="1" Padding="3,0,3,0">
        <!-- (ellided brushes for brevity) -->

        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
      </Border>

      <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
      <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper"
             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
             Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

The `ContentPresenter` is where the header text is displayed -- you can see that has its `HorizontalAlignment` set to the control's `HorizontalContentAlignment` (TemplateBinding).  Hence all that's needed is to set that style property on the control type `DataGridColumnHeader`.